# Style and font from a document

Tags: fonts, layout

I have recently found those really nice notes:

[Introduction to geometric measure theory](http://web.stanford.edu/class/math285/ts-gmt.pdf)

Do some of you have any idea of the style or font used in this document? I would like to write in a similar fashion.

Comment: If you have the .pdf file, you'll find with your viewer (File -> Properties)

Comment: ask the author ;) 
Leon Simon
Beijing, China, February 2014
lsimon@stanford.edu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening the document and checking the font list, it appears to use GaramondX (The NewG8 family of Type1 fonts) as the body font and Mathtime 2 (the MT2* family) as the main math font, with a few symbols from Computer Modern and something or other, somewhere, from Pazo math.

At a cursory examination, it uses Computer Modern `\mathcal` instead of MathTime 2, Holey Roman `\mathbb`, lining rather than old-style numbers, and upright rather than slanted Greek Θ.

Comment: Also Cormorant Garamond could be good because version 3.601 (2020-04-12), it package provides for `LaTeX, pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX`. https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cormorantgaramond

Comment: @Sebastiano Although `garamondx` was the font this PDF actually uses, there are certainly good alternatives!  For example, you could compile in `unicode-math` with Garamond Math.

Comment: Very kind Davislor I have seen the font used in the pdf `File→Properties` and I am agree totally with you. However your answer for me it is approved.